# Is adding a new collation to running mysql server simple?

Tags: mysql, collation

mysql version:  5.5.55-0+deb7u1-log - (Debian)

The server has a couple dozen or so utf8mb4_* collation settings but not `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` which I'd like to install.

Is this something that can be installed on the fly? This is a production server so I'd like to know if this is a dead simple process.

Comment: *"Is this something that can be installed on the fly? This is a production server so I'd like to know if this is a dead simple process."* .. Well unfortunately   it is not totally plug and play .. See the manual -> [Adding a Character Set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-character-set.html)

Comment: Is adding a character set different than adding a collation? This is part of my confusion on this.

Comment: *"Is adding a character set different than adding a collation? This is part of my confusion on this"* Well the manual also mentiones about [Adding a Collation to a Character Set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-collation.html) also...  Which might be possible to do without recompiling MySQL... (forgot to mention that in mine other comment)

Comment: *"Is adding a character set different than adding a collation? This is part of my confusion on this."*  Pretty sure [Character Sets, Collations, Unicode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset.html)  explains it

Comment: Definitely not a simple process. It would be better to just upgrade to a newer version that already has utf8mb4_unicde_520_ci configured.